# Nodejs export with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, async-await, export

Sooo it's another async/await question. I use npm ORM to create an edit function for my models, and this works out perfectly using this code:

```
module.exports = {
    edit: (model, id, data) => {
        model.get(id, (err, result) => {
            result.save(data)
        })
    }
}
```

I learned about async and await the other day but when I was experimenting with it, it didn't matter what I do I always got the following error:

"Missing Model.get() callback"

Please help me where I'm going wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model.get` doesn't return a promise, use `getAsync` instead :

```
module.exports = {
    edit: async (model, id, data) => {
        let result = await model.getAsync(id);
        result.save(data)
        return "done";
    }
}
```

call it like this :

```
let service = require("./service");

 service.edit(model,id,data).then( data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Ughhh I totally forgot reading about async in the orm docs! I read about that when I didn't know what async/await was, thank you so much, it works perfectly :)

Comment: is there btw a way to not have to do '.then( data => console.log(data))' ? Just have that be done in the function itself?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: after service.edit(model,id,date) you have ".then( data => console.log(data))" is there a way to just. console.log(service.edit(model,id,data) instead of needing a .then

Comment: Never mind I got it now. If you wrap an async around it and do await before it (when wanting to define a variable) it works without the pending

Comment: goood job bro :)